# Erro ao incluir biblioteca usando Linux

Tags: c, arquivo, biblioteca

Estou apenas tentando compilar exemplos do livro e obtenho **fatal error: No such file or directory** ao tentar incluir *conio.h, io.h* e até *curses.h*.

Li no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux) e foi sugerido justamente esta *curses.h*, a qual obtenho erro. Por que isso acontece e com qual biblioteca devo utilizar para fazer manipulação de **arquivos bufferizados** utilizando Linux (Fedora 23)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`conio.h` e `io.h` são bibliotecas normalmente encontradas nos compiladores para Windows. Não fazem parte do ISO C. Portanto, é natural que outras plataformas não o incluam. A não ser que tenha ótimos motivos, nunca dependa de extensões específicas de uma plataforma.

A curses.h está disponível no Linux, mas é preciso instalá-la primeiro. Se estiver usando o Ubuntu, use o comando `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` para instalá-la.

No Fedora, tente `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`.

Answer (score 2):

Pará completar a resposta acima de mim, se você precisa mesmo de incluir todas essas bibliotecas siga estes passos:

Instale ncurses e faça download do ficheiro gconio.h(http://www.wence.vandermeersch.org/gconio/gconio.h).

Coloque gconio.h na sua INC_DIR ou na pasta dos seu projecto.

Por fim utilize estes includes

```
#include <ncurses.h>   
#include <gconio.h>//ou "gconio.h" depende da sua localização
#include <asm/io.h>
```